# "...This question is unclear, or not useful..."

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, tooltips

Regarding the text that appears when you hover over the down vote button: Could this be reworded please. I could mark a high percentage of questions on Stack Overflow as 'not useful' that are about things I don't care about. Even questions in tags I am interested in may not be of use to me, that doesn't make it a bad question.

"Not useful" is too ambiguous.

How about something like "This question does not show any research effort, is unclear in what it asks or is likely to be of no use to the tagged communities."

Maybe something different for meta, like: "You disagree with the author" as I'm pretty sure the above rules don't apply.

Comment: Huh?  Your feature request is not at all clear.

Comment: Forgive me, I thought you'd understand that is the text that appears when you hover over the downvote button. I guess the amount of people not knowing that shows how little it's read / understood.

Comment: @user3791372 I think everyone has understood that. So what's your feature request? If you want to replace that text, what is it to be replaced with?

Comment: It doesn't say *not useful to me*, does it?

Comment: The tooltip doesn't say "this isn't useful *to me*". You should be able to tell if a question is generally a useful question or not. That's what the tooltip is for.

Comment: "Even questions in tags I am interested in may not be of use to me" Maybe it's because sometimes, you should not consider the question as being bound to a tag, but to an aggregate of tags which gives more sense.

Comment: Not useful to whom? Useful to the person who already knows the answer? Not useful to someone who likes ponies? Not useful to me? Not useful to someone who is just dipping into the language? Not useful to...

Comment: @JonW for those who lack the skill and who aren't able to tell, please define a useful question.

Comment: @user3791372: Useful: ["able to be used for a practical purpose or in several ways."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=useful+definition&btnG=&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @user3791372 If you "lack the skill" to define whether a question is useful or not, then simply don't vote. It isn't mandatory

Comment: I was getting ready to ask the same question, good thing I didn't. I would have said "...not useful for future readers".

Answer (score 19):

I think this is just a matter of semantics, and ultimately pointless semantics at that....

I think users on SO are not complete morons and can make the difference between "not useful" and "doesn't relate to me".  I've never coded Go in my life, but I still understand that they are useful to someone, somewhere.

If you're smart enough to code and get involved in SO, I'm pretty sure you're smart enough to "do your part" in active reading and understand the intent behind the wording of "not useful"

Comment: I disagree with your answer, therefore it's not useful.

Comment: I won't even engage in that.  Have a good day

Comment: So you've ignored all the comments above, I see? You're still using "useful to **me**" as the criteria, when it's already been explained to you that's not what it means

Comment: @Clive: He's just being a pedantic troll. No sense engaging him further.

Comment: @Clive I didn't say it isn't useful to me. I wrote "I disagree... therefore it's not useful". To me isn't #even implied. Just a remark on how people down vote here

Comment: lol ok. As you wish. Have fun playing word games with yourself, funnily enough I have other things to do...

Comment: @user3791372 yeah this is meta, not SO.... we are all aware meta votes are based on agreement, not usefulness.....  your point is?

Comment: @Julldar Interestingly enough, my answer has exactly one downvote as of now (and it got that one early on); yours has none.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling indeed interesting.... but I'm trying to see what you imply by that? :P  people agree with mine but not with yours, saying basically the same thing? :P even if to be fair, yours has a point mine doesn't, talking about native language and whatnot

Comment: @Julldar I think it says that someone disagreed with my answer but not with yours (enough to downvote, anyway). :)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling fair enough... but we basically say the SAME THING :P

Answer (score 15):

Stack Exchange's purpose is, broadly speaking, to increase the corpus of knowledge on the Internet.

**A question's usefulness should be judged in that light:**

- If a question will serve to increase the general corpus of knowledge on the Internet, then it is generally a good question, even if it is of no interest to *you* specifically.
- If a question does not serve to increase the corpus of knowledge on the Internet, then it is often a bad question.

Exceptions do exist, but that's a general rule of thumb that would apply in most cases.

We could obviously change the downvote arrow text to something like "This question does not appear to seek to increase the corpus of knowledge on the Internet" (with a corresponding change to the upvote arrow tooltip), but then again who am I to judge *that?*

Also, what percentage of people who understand the current text will understand that? Remember that the Stack Exchange network is international in nature and many users' first language is not English.

Comment: So many points I could disagree with there

Comment: @user3791372 Well, that's your perogative. By all means feel free to post your own (self-)answer with a proposed solution, and let the community vote on the alternatives.

Comment: "Also, what percentage of people who understand the current text will understand that?" +1. English not being my first language, I'm glad that tooltips are generic and simple. Further explanations on the website usage should remain in FAQs and Help pages IMO